# Laravel. is .JOIN supposed to filter results?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

So far from what i know, `.join` is just to join and does not filter anything. But i have run into an issue where it seems like it is being filtered.

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($borrowers); $i++) { 
            $borrowed_books[$i] = Borrower::join('borrows', 'borrows.borrower_id', '=', 'borrowers.id')
                        ->join('late_returns', 'late_returns.borrow_id', '=', 'borrows.id')
                        ->join('books', 'borrows.book_id', '=', 'books.id')
                        ->where('borrowers.id', '=', $borrowers[$i]->id)
                        ->get(['borrowers.id','books.book_title','books.year','books.author', 'books.publisher_name', 'books.ISBN', 'borrows.issue_date', 'borrows.return_date', 'late_returns.late_return_fines', 'late_returns.overdue_days']);
        }
        return view('admin.borrowers', compact('borrowers', 'search', 'borrowed_books'));
```

The query section `->join('late_returns')` causes  only books present in late_return table to show up. Which is
[image]

Where as everything with borrower_id 1 should show up.
[image]

The intended rows are shown when everything related to late_returns table is removed from the query. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Instead try the below method, it should return everything you want

$borrowers_ids = $borrowers->pluck('id'); // assuming $borrowers is a collection

$borrows = Borrow::query()
                ->whereHas('borrower', function ($query) use ($borrowers_ids) {
                    $query->whereIn('id', $borrowers_ids);
                })
                ->with('lateReturn', 'book')
                ->get();
```